# Flutterアプリの起動→Google sign inを押したとき、エラーになってしまう。

Tags: android-studio, firebase, flutter, dart

Flutter大学さんの「Flutterの教科書」内で、「Riverpodでの状態管理」で、教科書の説明通りにGithub経由でCloneしてきたサンプルリポジトリのコードの書き換え等を行い、

flutter pub add fake_cloud_firestore
で、モックの注入を行い　Google Sign Inのボタンが表示されるところまでは、ビルドができたのですが、Google Sign Inボタンを押してGoogleアカウントでのサインインを行った所、

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
```

とエラーが表示されてしまい、ログイン後に画面の遷移を行うことができません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### これまで試したこと

SHA-1のフィンガープリント貼り付け、FirebaseにAndroidアプリの追加を行いました。

flutter pub outdated
↓
flutter pub upgrade outdated_package
で、Flutterパッケージのアップグレードを行った後に、

flutter pub outdated
を使い、cloud_firestore とfirebase_auth 、google_sign_in 、intl を最新バージョンにアップグレードを行いました。